# How to get the next Max Id using Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am learning SQL/Stored Procedures. I have the **table with idGroup and idDraft**. Now **one idgroup can have many idDrafts**. Below is the scenario.

```
idGroup idDraft
  1       1
  1       2
  1       3
  2       1
  2       2
```

Now I want to write a Stored Procedure where I can pass the idGroup and it will return the next Max idDraft.

**Output Expected:**

So If I pass idGroup as 1 I should get value as 4, if I pass idGroup as 2 I should get value as 3. Below is my attempt. Please guide me.

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`DEV`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetNextDraftID`(
            IN p_idGroup int(11),
            OUT p_NextID int(11)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE tempMax int(11);

    SELECT 
        ss.idDraft Into tempMax
    FROM
        tblDraft ss
    WHERE
        idGroup = p_idGroup
    GROUP BY idDraft
    ORDER BY idDraft DESC
    LIMIT 1;

    IF ISNULL(tempMax) THEN
        SET p_NextID = 1;
    else
        SET p_NextID = tempMax +1;
    end IF;

END
```

I am a beginner so I don't even know how to test this stored procedure. Please guide me here. Do I need to make more changes here.

Comment: try `CALL GetNextDraftID(1);`

Comment: what's the purpose of this function? Are you going to insert the value returned from the stored procedure back into a new table row at some point? If so, this sounds like a recipe for concurrency problems and duplicated records. You'd be better off with a Drafts table with an auto_increment field, and then to get a new ID, you insert a record into the Drafts table, get the ID created, and then insert that into the other table against the appropriate group ID. That way the DB ensures that there are no duplicate draft IDs. And it works even if multiple users do it  simultaneously.